How to globally enforce lower case snake case on all model binding from requests
I am using the following to ensure serializing shifts my variables to lowercase snakecase as follows:
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = 
       JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower; 
});

However, I am noticing it does not work the opposite way. I have a form which I am appending data to and from my testing in order for the model to bind correctly I need to annotate each field with:
[ModelBinder(Name = "test_item")]

This kind of defeats the purpose of my global setting and I am curious if I am able to add something similar for the deserializing/model binding from requests.

In ASP.NET Core, JsonNamingPolicy affects only JSON output, not model binding for incoming requests. For model binding, there's no built-in way to automatically convert snake case to camel case. to achieve your requirement you could use the custom model binder
